# Transform filter function to Python code

Tags: python, filter, signal-processing

I'm trying to understand how to transform a filter, in this case a Notch(stopband) filter, to Python but I don't know how.

```
x(n)=-2*x(n)/(-0.9*x(n) -0.9*x(n-1))
```

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using numpy arrays, this should work:

```
x[1:]=-2*x[1:]/(-0.9*x[1:]-0.9*x[:-1])
```

this changes your array in place, but you could just as easily assign it to a new array.

```
y=-2*x[1:]/(-0.9*x[1:]-0.9*x[:-1])
```

Note that your algorithm isn't really well defined for the 0th element, so my translation leaves `x[0]` unchanged.

**EDIT**

To change an iterable to a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
x=np.array(iterable)  #pretty easy :) although there could be more efficient ways depending on where "iterable" comes from.
```

Comment: nice answer, you should add what he needs to import. Also for the op, if you are using windows, you will have to dl numpy: http://scipy.github.com/content.html

Comment: @pyInTheSky -- You don't need to import anything for this piece of code ... (Of course, numpy needs to be imported somewhere to get a numpy array in the first place, but it doesn't need to be here), but I guess that's a reasonable idea...

Comment: OP seemed new to python, so props to you for adding the edit.  I find it's always nice when you get an answer that can be executed as is.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = []
#prime your result, that is, add the initial values to handle indexing
lower_bound = #
upper_bound = #
for n in range(lower_bound,upper_bound):
    result.append( 2*result[n]/(-0.9*result[n] -0.9*result[n-1]) )
```

Comment: This should raise an IndexError since `result[lower_bound]` doesn't exist yet.  And, if result starts out as something other than an empty list, then you're appending to result instead of changing the values in it.

Comment: For this sort of operation, you're much better off using numpy arrays to speed up the for-loop as in mgilson's answer.

Comment: Yeah, I'll be using numpy arrays.